# is "my passport is processing" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I met one friend. He was about to travel, but he hadn't had a passport yet. So he submitted his passport application. He told me "my passport is processing". I was wondering his words missed something? To my opinion, the correct one should be "my passport is under processing" or "my passport is being processed". But I am not sure if his version is also ok?

Answer (score 2):

Since a passport can't "do" anything, the action verb in "my passport is processing" is out of place and would not sound right to a native English speaker. "My passport is under processing" is a little better, but again, it would probably not be used by a native speaker, who would use your third version: "My passport is being processed."

Comment: Should I not bother you, I would like to ask this. When I use ATM here, it often says "system is processing". Is this correct?

Comment: @Vince No bother at all! In that context, "System is processing" is correct. The system, although not sentient, is capable of certain defined actions including processing, so the action verb makes sense. A passport, in contrast, is an inanimate object. (If the ATM ever says "System is worried about your haircut," though, we will all have cause to worry.)

Comment: is "my passport is pending" correct?

Comment: @Vince Yes, "My passport is pending" sounds fine. However, it won't get you through customs.

Answer (score 0):

> My passport is processing.
>   *my passport is being processed*

would be understandable that his passport has not finished being processed.  Although his passport itself can not "process" anything (being inanimate) expressions may get used to *personify* objects and give them animate qualities.

> My application is stuck.
>   *the process for my application is being delayed*
>
> My car disappeared.
>   *someone stole my car*

Comment: is "my passport is pending." correct?

Comment: That would certainly be understood as "my application for a passport is still being processed", usually your sentence would be part of a conversation which provides more context.